# Cannot access an Object's property

Tags: reactjs, mobx

so I have a function that sorts an array of activities based on their date. However, after sorting, it seems that I can't access an activity's property even though the activity is not null or undefined. Since English is not my native language, if there's anything unclear please tell me so that I can update the question. Thanks in advance guys.

The interface:

```
export interface IActivity {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  category: string;
  date: Date | null;
  city: string;
  venue: string;
}
```

The function:

```
sortActivitiesByDate(activities: IActivity[]) {
    const sortedActivities = activities.sort(
      (a, b) => new Date(a.date).getTime() - new Date(b.date).getTime()
    );
    sortedActivities.forEach((activity) => {
      const test = toJS(activity);
      console.log(test); //has props in it
      console.log(test.description); //undefined
    });
  }
```

The console result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WamG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replcae `console.log(test.description);` with `console.log(test.activity.description);` and you will get your value in console.